# What does "come in" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "take part in trading"?

> "Optimism is quite high but everyone is a little bit nervous about when we should come in, what's the president going to do, what changes are going to come through, so they've been holding back, so loan growth is going to be a big focus of these numbers," he added.

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/04/18/us-banks-are-now-truly-turning-the-page-asset-manager-says.html

Comment: Literally, it just means "enter", as it would in any other context.  The question is exactly what they're entering.

Answer (score 1):

I think it does mean "take part in trading". I think he is using the phrase to imply "come in to the marketplace" or "come in with our money to the market" or "come bringing our assets".

Answer (score -1):

The author could also imply that we should be optimistic when taking a risk when it involves getting a loan.

According to the article's title, the article speaks in the context of the US banks giving out loans so in that context, it also perhaps refers to the 2008 financial crisis in the US caused by too many loans given out and people becoming bankrupt and not being able to pay back. So perhaps the focus is more on banks in the US being more cautious when giving out loans by checking the credit of each individual to ensure they are able to pay it back. So this involves stricter laws in order to avoid another economic crackdown.

Your question seems to be a bit vague but this is what I had in mind. Perhaps if you can elaborate a little more.

Cheers!

Comment: The question in the title is pretty straight-forward. You haven't actually answered it.